# Filling data from CSV to an existing Excel template in C#

Tags: c#, .net, excel, com

I have a requirement where we have predefined Excel template with headers and some formatting. Through code we should be able to map data from a CSV file and fill the data to the template and finally save the excel as a new file, so that the template is not disturbed.

Can I get an idea or some sample code snippet to proceed?

Comment: And?  What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the code which is working for me

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Globalization;

namespace ExcelTemplateFiller
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Excel.Application excelApp = null;
            Excel.Worksheet xlSheet;
            Excel.Workbook xlBook;
            try
            {
                excelApp = new Excel.Application();
                string templatePath = @"..\..\ExcelTemplate\FTPLogReport.xltx";
                string CSVPath = @"..\..\Input\08Oct2013_FTPLogReport.csv";
                string OutputPath = @"..\..\Output\08Oct2013_FTPLogReport.xlsx";

                templatePath = Path.GetFullPath(templatePath);
                CSVPath = Path.GetFullPath(CSVPath);
                OutputPath = Path.GetFullPath(OutputPath);

                xlBook = (Excel.Workbook)excelApp.Workbooks.Open(templatePath, Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
                    Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
                    Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
                    Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
                    Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
                    Missing.Value, Missing.Value,
                    Missing.Value, Missing.Value);

                int row = 2;

                DataTable dtCSV = CsvFileToDatatable(CSVPath, true);

                foreach (DataRow dr in dtCSV.Rows)
                {
                    excelApp.Cells[row, 1] = dr[0].ToString();
                    excelApp.Cells[row, 2] = dr[1].ToString();
                    excelApp.Cells[row, 3] = dr[2].ToString();
                    excelApp.Cells[row, 4] = dr[3].ToString();
                    excelApp.Cells[row, 5] = dr[4].ToString();

                    row++;
                }



                xlSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
                xlSheet.Name = "08Oct2013";

                object oFilename = OutputPath;
                object oFileFormat = Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault;
                object oPassword = Missing.Value;
                object oWriteResPassword = Missing.Value;
                object oReadOnlyRecommended = false;
                object oCreateBackup = false;

                Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode AccessMode = Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange;
                object oConflictResolution = false;
                object oAddToMru = true;
                object oTextCodepage = Missing.Value;
                object oTextVisualLayout = Missing.Value;
                object oSaveChanges = true;
                object oRouteWorkbook = Missing.Value;

                excelApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
                xlBook.SaveAs(oFilename, oFileFormat, oPassword, oWriteResPassword, oReadOnlyRecommended, oCreateBackup, AccessMode, oConflictResolution, oAddToMru, oTextCodepage, oTextVisualLayout);
                xlBook.Close(oSaveChanges, oFilename, oRouteWorkbook);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                excelApp.Quit();
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelApp);
                GC.Collect();
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30000);
            }

        }

        private static DataTable CsvFileToDatatable(string path, bool IsFirstRowHeader)
        {
            string header = "No";
            string sql = string.Empty;
            DataTable dtCSV = null;
            string pathOnly = string.Empty;
            string fileName = string.Empty;

            try
            {
                pathOnly = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
                fileName = Path.GetFileName(path);

                sql = @"SELECT * FROM [" + fileName + "]";

                if (IsFirstRowHeader)
                {
                    header = "Yes";
                }

                using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + pathOnly + ";Extended Properties=\"Text;HDR=" + header + "\""))
                {
                    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, connection))
                    {
                        using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd))
                        {
                            dtCSV = new DataTable();
                            dtCSV.Locale = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
                            adapter.Fill(dtCSV);
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            return dtCSV;
        }
    }
}
```

Below link has helped me on. 
[MSDN link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2cfe12c3-169a-44bc-ad7e-9dd274c3a1f3/c-opening-excel-templatexlt-adding-data-and-saving-to-new-worksheetxls?forum=vsto)